# Why selected row values is not displaying on devexpress client side using ASP.Net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, devexpress

I am trying to display selected rows on client side when user select one row and click the button.

I tried the code from this [devexpress link](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientGridView_GetSelectedFieldValuestopic)

I tried with same scenario in my code, but it throws error

Here is my code

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" Width="100%" SettingsBehavior-AllowSelectByRowClick="True" OnSelectionChanged="btnSearch_Click">
    <Settings HorizontalScrollBarMode="Visible" ShowFilterRow="True" ShowGroupedColumns="True" ShowTitlePanel="True" ShowGroupPanel="True" />

    <SettingsSearchPanel Visible="True" />
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn  ShowSelectCheckbox="true" VisibleIndex="0"></dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Status" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="0"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="WorksheetID" VisibleIndex="1"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="POTitle" VisibleIndex="2" Width="200px" ExportWidth="100" MinWidth="100"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="FromStoreName" VisibleIndex="3"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="FromPONumber" VisibleIndex="4"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ToStoreName" VisibleIndex="5"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ToPONumber" VisibleIndex="6"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="FromStoreID" VisibleIndex="7"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ToStoreID" VisibleIndex="8"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="FromPlacementStatus" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="9"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataDateColumn FieldName="FromDatePlaced" VisibleIndex="10"></dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ToPlacementStatus" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="11"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataDateColumn FieldName="ToDatePlaced" VisibleIndex="12"></dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataDateColumn FieldName="LastUpdated" VisibleIndex="13"></dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="IssueQty" VisibleIndex="14">            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="IssueValue" VisibleIndex="15"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ReceivedQty" VisibleIndex="16"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ReceivedValue" VisibleIndex="17"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="DiscrepancyQty" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="18"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Discrepancy" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="19"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    </Columns>

</dx:ASPxGridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HQMatajer13 %>" 
    SelectCommand="select top 10000 
        CASE WHEN FromStatus = 0 AND (ToStatus = 0 OR ToStatus IS NULL OR (ToStoreID = 0 AND WorksheetID = 0)) THEN 'Open'
       WHEN ToStatus = 0 AND (FromStatus IS NULL OR (FromStoreID = 0 AND WorksheetID = 0)) THEN 'Open'
       WHEN FromStatus = 2 AND (ToStatus = 2 OR (ToStoreID = 0 AND WorksheetID = 0)) THEN 'Closed'
       WHEN ToStatus = 2 AND (FromStoreID = 0 AND WorksheetID = 0) THEN 'Closed'
       ELSE 'Partial' 
    END Status,
    F_ViewInventoryTransferList2.WorksheetID,
    F_ViewInventoryTransferList2.POTitle,
    F_ViewInventoryTransferList2.FromStoreName,
    F_ViewInventoryTransferList2.FromPONumber,
    F_ViewInventoryTransferList2.ToStoreName,
    F_ViewInventoryTransferList2.ToPONumber,
    F_ViewInventoryTransferList2.FromStoreID,
    F_ViewInventoryTransferList2.ToStoreID,
    CASE FromIsPlaced WHEN 0 THEN 'Not placed' WHEN 1 THEN 'Placed' ELSE 'Unknown' END FromPlacementStatus,
    F_ViewInventoryTransferList2.FromDatePlaced,
    CASE ToIsPlaced WHEN 0 THEN 'Not placed' WHEN 1 THEN 'Placed' ELSE 'Unknown' END ToPlacementStatus,
    F_ViewInventoryTransferList2.ToDatePlaced,
    F_ViewInventoryTransferList2.LastUpdated,
    F_ViewInventoryTransferList2.IssueQty,
    F_ViewInventoryTransferList2.IssueValue,
    F_ViewInventoryTransferList2.ReceivedQty,
    F_ViewInventoryTransferList2.ReceivedValue,
    CASE WHEN (ToStoreID = 0 AND WorksheetID = 0) THEN 0
         WHEN (FromStoreID = 0 AND WorksheetID = 0) THEN 0
         ELSE F_ViewInventoryTransferList2.ReceivedQty + F_ViewInventoryTransferList2.IssueQty
  END DiscrepancyQty,
  CASE WHEN (ToStoreID = 0 AND WorksheetID = 0) THEN 0
       WHEN (FromStoreID = 0 AND WorksheetID = 0) THEN 0    
       ELSE F_ViewInventoryTransferList2.ReceivedValue + F_ViewInventoryTransferList2.IssueValue
  END Discrepancy
from F_ViewInventoryTransferList2">
</asp:SqlDataSource>                

  <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" AutoPostBack="False" runat="server" Text="test" UseSubmitBehavior="False">

      <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {
    ASPxGridView1.GetSelectedFieldValues('WorksheetID', OnGetSelectedFieldValues);
 }" />
  </dx:ASPxButton>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
<script>
    function OnGetSelectedFieldValues(selectedValues) {
        //listBox.ClearItems();
        alert("Workingggg...");
        if (selectedValues.length == 0) return;
        for (i = 0; i < selectedValues.length; i++) {
            s = "";
            for (j = 0; j < selectedValues[i].length; j++) {
                s = s + selectedValues[i][j] + "&nbsp;";
            }
            //listBox.AddItem(s);
            alert(s);
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Error Msg**
[image: error msg screenshot]

> Even I try server side to retrieve data, it throws same error. This is that [link](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E319/how-to-use-a-getselectedfieldvalues-method-to-obtain-values-of-several-columns-at-once) for server side what I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because you have to specify a `KeyFieldNameColumn`, like a `PrimaryKey` in SQL, but this is for DevExpress table.

Based in your code I think is `WorksheetID` (but you can change by another FieldName), so you have to change next line:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" Width="100%" SettingsBehavior-AllowSelectByRowClick="True" OnSelectionChanged="btnSearch_Click" KeyFieldName="WorksheetID">
```

Comment: I dont remember now this but I use always primary key of data source in a hiden column